# Selective error checking in Bash script

Tags: unix, error-checking

So I have a bash script as follows:

```
Command1 -- If error occurs, ignore error and continue execution
Command2 -- If error occurs, ignore error and continue execution
Command3 -- If error occurs, stop execution, exit the script with the error
Command4 -- If error occurs, stop execution, exit the script with the error
Command5 -- If error occurs, stop execution, exit the script with the error
Command6 -- If error occurs, ignore error and continue execution
```

I need to check specific commands to see if they threw an error and if they did, exit the script with an error code (Comand3,4,5). However, I cannot use "set -e" because I wish to purposefully ignore certain commands as well(Command1,2,6).

Is there any way I can combine the commands 3, 4 and 5 within a function and run it such that the script exits if any of these commands throw an error? Also, if I wish to do some cleanup before the script exits (similar to catch clause in Java, where the code executes if there is an exception), how can I do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
Command1
Command2
Command3 || exit
Command4 || exit
Command5 || exit
Command6
```

or

```
Command1
Command2
Command3 && Command4 && Command5 || exit
Command6
```

To do your cleanup:

```
cleanup() {
    # commands here that do your cleanup
    # ...
}

Command3 && Command4 && Command5 || { cleanup; exit; }
```

Comment: Great, shall try that. And how about if any of these 3 commands fail, I need it do some cleanup before exiting?

Comment: Hmm, its still not working for me, I tried combining commands 3,4,5 into a function and am testing the return value as : commandFunction; if [ $? -ne 0 ] then cleanup; exit 1; fi  And am returning 0 from the commandFunction if execution reaches all the way at the end successfully. What am I doing wrong? The script stops in case of errors, but my cleanup does not execute.

Comment: Show your function. I suspect the problem is that you did something like `{ cmd1; cmd2; cmd3; }` instead of `{ cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3; }`